# Restricting a node within another in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit, trying to build basic Breakout game. The problem I'm facing is that I can't restrict the paddle within the screen (that's yet another node with blue texture as shown in image). When I move the paddle it goes beyond the screen limits. 
I've applied physics to both, screen area and the paddle but no luck.[image]

Comment: How are you moving the paddle, and how did you define the physics body for the background?

Comment: let's say I'm doing it by tapping and holding on the left, right corner to move in that respective direction. I defined physics using Attribute inspector, by enabling physics definition.

Comment: Are you using an edge loop for the background? Also, are you moving the paddle by apply a force or an impulse to it or are you changing the x and y values directly?

Comment: Yes I'm using edge loop for background, and moving paddle by changing the x value directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paddle doesn't collide appropriately with the edge because you are moving it by changing its position directly. To participate in the physics simulation, the paddle must be moved by setting its velocity or by applying a force or impulse to its physics body. For example,

```
for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    if (location.x < size.width/2.0) {
        paddle.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-scale, 0))
    }
    else {
        paddle.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(scale, 0))
    }
}
```

where `scale` determines the amount of momentum that is applied to the body in the `x` dimension.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you can constrain the paddle's `x` position to be within a set range by

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: CGRectGetMinX(view.frame), upperLimit: CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame))
let constraint = SKConstraint.positionX(range)
paddle.constraints = [constraint]
```

Add the above to the `didMoveToView` method.

Comment: no luck. I've added four Color Sprite objects around the screen area and applied bounding rectangle physics on it. Now I've a ball in the scene too, and that ball doesn't go out of the screen however paddle still goes out.

Comment: Did you set the paddle's `collisionBitMask` to a 0? It should be  `UInt32.max`, the default value.

Comment: See my updated answer for a different approach to restrict the `x` position of the paddle